# Huge input lag in C++ DX9 application when having many entities

Tags: input, directx9, lag

So I have created a 2D game engine used for creating top down singleplayer shooters and now I encounter some massive input lags when I have spawned a few entities (maybe 20 opponents). This results in that the mouse and keyboard input is delayed: I move and turn around, shoot weapons and when I abort pressing anything then the input is still processed for 1 or 2 seconds. This makes the game unplayable. I reduced lag a bit when refusing to use WM_MOUSEMOVE in my WndProc and use GetCursorPos instead, but still, the input lag is there.
Is this normal when using a single threaded application? I run everything (WndProc, game processings, drawings) in the main thread. Do I need to use multithreading in order to let the game run fluent?
I know DX9 is dated, but it can't be caused by DX9 itself, since many games have been written with it, and those games even manage much more spawned entities than my game.

Comment: You have not shown us enough of your code for us to spot what you've done wrong. Please edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: the smallest set of code and instructions we can use to reproduce this problem in a new project.

Comment: Do you have any clue where the hold-up is? Do you have a huge number of unprocessed Win32 messages in your message loop? Does creating the Direct3D resources take a long time? Is it the first render frame after the new spawns?